# How to get rid of this exponentiation

Tags: calculus

I would like to remove exponentiation in this equation $y=x^t$ and use only multiplication or division. I have $x, t$ and $\ln(x)$. Is it possible?

Comment: $\ln y=t\ln x$ is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $y=x^t$

This gives you: $\ln(y) = \ln(x^t) = t \ln(x)\quad\implies \quad \ln(y) = t \ln(x)$

Here we use the rule of logarithms (which applies to "$\ln$" as well):

> $$\log(a^b) = b \log (a)$$

Comment: So now instead using pow I have to use exp. What if I could also use addition and subtraction?

Comment: That's about as simplified as you can get. You could write: $t = \dfrac{\ln(y)}{\ln(x)}$

Comment: To solve for $y$ given $t$ and $\ln(x)$, evaluate $t\ln(x) = a$, so $\ln(y) = a \implies y = e^a$. I.e. $y = \exp(t\ln(x))$

Answer (score 1):

When $a>0$ then we are always allowed to have $$\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$$ So take a Neperian logarithm from both sides of your identity.

Comment: What is the Neperian logarithm? Natural log? +1

Comment: yes. it is the natural one.